# I can no longer install packages in R, I am the administrator and only user

Tags: r, installation

Recently something changed with my R installation and I couldn't install any packages as the library was "not writable".

I uninstalled R, and have re-installed it (R/4.0.5)... The problem persists.

```
> if (!requireNamespace("BiocManager", quietly=TRUE))
+   install.packages("BiocManager")
Warning in install.packages("BiocManager") :
  'lib = "C:/Program Files/R/R-4.0.5/library"' is not writable
Error in install.packages("BiocManager") : unable to install packages
> .libPaths()
[1] "C:/Program Files/R/R-4.0.5/library"
>
```

I rely heavily on R, and really need optimal function. What do I need to do to make sure it installs programs to a place it can access. I have had numerous installations in different directories previously and this seemed to trigger the problem. I've removed them all as far as I can tell.

This seems like a basic issue which should be an easy fix.

Comment: Something in your configuration went awry. Packages should by default be installed in the *user directory* (`%USERPROFILE%\Documents\R\win-library`), not in the (write-protected) application root. What’s the value of your `.libPath()`? Do you have any custom configuration files (`.Rprofile`)?

Comment: Incidentally I have some issues with the default location: it should go into `%LOCALAPPDATA%` instead of cluttering the user documents folder (which is quite rude behaviour), So I recommend re-configuring this location (via the environment variable `R_LIBS_USER`).